# failed to mount Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, mount, fstab

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a laptop have a windows 7 installed ...works fine for the few first week until I have a problem of " read only file system " it was self fixed by restarting and pressing F ... this problem begin to be more ad more frequent till I have the mount failed.  It is as following

```
mount: mounting /dev/disk/by-uuid/e49d5efb-d3ed..... on /root failed:Invailed argument
mount:mounting/dev on /root/dev failed no such file or directory 
mount:mounting/sys on /root/sys failed:No such file or directory 
mount :mounting/proc on /root/proc failed:no such file or directory
Target file system doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
no init found try passing init = bootarg
BusyBox v1.2....

#and it begins in (initramfs)
```

I don't know what to do next ''' but i will surely reinstall it i posted here because i am a beginner and want to learn how to fix it

Comment: Can you boot into your Windows side at this point? If not, your drive may be faulty. You could try booting from a LIVE CD/USB and verifying your hard drive status.